# Tank auth in different system（Mac and Linux） create different password Hash code

Tags: php, codeigniter, md5, tankauth

I used mac as web sever, and took codeigniter as framework. For authetication, I applied tank auth. One issue occurs:

Before: I used mac as web sever, logging in is good.

Now: I used linux as web server. I imported the same database, and the website run well. However, i can't log in.

So I tested registering using the same password in mac and linux, found that it create different password Hash code .

Linux:

```
$P$Bh3B8uGDw0yGO1e/ytCUw2jXcswkso1
```

Mac:

```
$2a$08$jBCiR79fHN6xzOw5sB09beFifwU08nQdO0Au8P3hxSvIUnoepKfwW
```

My question is : is this issue about system? or php version?

Or it's about md5() function of php?

I present some code of password hash in tank auth:

```
function PasswordHash($iteration_count_log2, $portable_hashes)
{
    $this->itoa64 = './0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';

    if ($iteration_count_log2 < 4 || $iteration_count_log2 > 31)
        $iteration_count_log2 = 8;
    $this->iteration_count_log2 = $iteration_count_log2;

    $this->portable_hashes = $portable_hashes;

    $this->random_state = microtime();
    if (function_exists('getmypid'))
        $this->random_state .= getmypid();
}

function get_random_bytes($count)
{
    $output = '';
    if (is_readable('/dev/urandom') &&
        ($fh = @fopen('/dev/urandom', 'rb'))) {
        $output = fread($fh, $count);
        fclose($fh);
    }

    if (strlen($output) < $count) {
        $output = '';
        for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i += 16) {
            $this->random_state =
                md5(microtime() . $this->random_state);
            $output .=
                pack('H*', md5($this->random_state));
        }
        $output = substr($output, 0, $count);
    }

    return $output;
}

function encode64($input, $count)
{
    $output = '';
    $i = 0;
    do {
        $value = ord($input[$i++]);
        $output .= $this->itoa64[$value & 0x3f];
        if ($i < $count)
            $value |= ord($input[$i]) << 8;
        $output .= $this->itoa64[($value >> 6) & 0x3f];
        if ($i++ >= $count)
            break;
        if ($i < $count)
            $value |= ord($input[$i]) << 16;
        $output .= $this->itoa64[($value >> 12) & 0x3f];
        if ($i++ >= $count)
            break;
        $output .= $this->itoa64[($value >> 18) & 0x3f];
    } while ($i < $count);

    return $output;
}
    function HashPassword($password)
{
    $random = '';

    if (CRYPT_BLOWFISH == 1 && !$this->portable_hashes) {
        $random = $this->get_random_bytes(16);
        $hash =
            crypt($password, $this->gensalt_blowfish($random));
        if (strlen($hash) == 60)
            return $hash;
    }

    if (CRYPT_EXT_DES == 1 && !$this->portable_hashes) {
        if (strlen($random) < 3)
            $random = $this->get_random_bytes(3);
        $hash =
            crypt($password, $this->gensalt_extended($random));
        if (strlen($hash) == 20)
            return $hash;
    }

    if (strlen($random) < 6)
        $random = $this->get_random_bytes(6);
    $hash =
        $this->crypt_private($password,
        $this->gensalt_private($random));
    if (strlen($hash) == 34)
        return $hash;

    # Returning '*' on error is safe here, but would _not_ be safe
    # in a crypt(3)-like function used _both_ for generating new
    # hashes and for validating passwords against existing hashes.
    return '*';
}
```

Any idea? I searched this issue in google but got little information, Could you kindly help me? thank you..

Oh, maybe it's about CRYPT_BLOWFISH. Linux don't have CRYPT_BLOWFISH.

Comment: Cf. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the solution myself.

The issue is about php version.

php 5.2 is not supported CRYPT_BLOWFISH, but php 5.3 is OK.

Thanks everybody.